# bouncycastle fails NTRU generation

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, bouncycastle, ntrusign

There are three types of default security levels of NTRU, implemented in bouncy-castle:

```
 1. NTRUSigningKeyGenerationParameters.TEST157
 2. NTRUSigningKeyGenerationParameters.APR2011_439
 3. NTRUSigningKeyGenerationParameters.APR2011_743
```

First two are generated normally, but when I try to generate the tird one, I get the next Exception:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Signing failed: too many retries (max=100)] with root cause
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Signing failed: too many retries (max=100)

Here is piece of my code:

```
NTRUSigningPrivateKeyParameters ntruSigningPrivateKeyParameters1 = null;

    NTRUSigner ntruSigner = new NTRUSigner(ntruSigningKeyGenerationParameters.getSigningParameters());

    try {
        ntruSigningPrivateKeyParameters1 = new NTRUSigningPrivateKeyParameters(ntruSigningPrivateKeyParameters.getEncoded(), ntruSigningKeyGenerationParameters);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ntruSigner.init(true, ntruSigningPrivateKeyParameters);
    byte [] res = ntruSigner.generateSignature();
```

Calling `ntruSigner.generateSignature()` with the third set of parameters leads to a such Exception.

Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: You know what happens when you go in for the leading edge; you may fall off. I would recommend sending this question to the bouncy castle dev mailing list instead. David or one of the other maintainers may be able to extend a hand and keep you on the edge :P Or take a look at the source code and see if you can change it for your specific case.

Comment: @owlstead you again =) thnx for the tip, I've already sent a letter to them

Comment: If they are able to help you please post the solution here as answer, and I'll vote up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it's a bug, so there are two solutions:

1. use another library - [tbuktu's github project](https://github.com/tbuktu/ntru/commit/8126929e32d00ed321e836e0792145dcbb6516df) (bouncy-castle is using it with some modifications, as I see)
2. download sources, catch the bug of this generation parameter, solve it and pack into library for a project

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a bug in the code. The problem is that the norm bound in the `APR2011_743` and `APR2011_743_PROD` parameter sets is too low which means that the signer is unable to generate a valid signature.

For `N=743`, `q=2048` and `beta=0.127` you should choose a norm bound of around 545 (see equation 10 in J. Hoffstein et al, Performance improvements and a baseline parameter generation algorithm for NTRUSign) but the parameter sets in BouncyCastle use `normBound=405`. Changing this solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the normBound does appear to fix the issue, however I should point out the NTRUSigner class is now deprecated in Bouncy Castle. The NTRU signing algorithm was shown to be badly broken just over a year ago. See:

http://www.di.ens.fr/~ducas/NTRUSign_Cryptanalysis/DucasNguyen_Learning.pdf

for details.